# moving files to multiple folders and zipping using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have requirement of moving files older than 7 days from a folder in to a sub folder and zip them and delete from source location.

folder structures are like. ( Files generate on these folders on daily basis)
C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country1
C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country2
C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country3

I need move them to a subfoldes inside and zip them and delete from source location.
C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country1\Archive
C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country2\Archive
C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country3\Archive

This is one interface. Like this i have 8 more interfaces which have files inside for different countries. The smae way of archiving older than 7 days need to be done for all 8 interfaces or main folders.

I just tried below code and it worked for me.

1.

---

```
$SourcePath = "C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country1"
$TargetPath = "C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country1\ARCHIVE"
$YourDirToCompress ="C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country1\ARCHIVE"

$SourcePath_1 = "C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country2"
$TargetPath_1 = "C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country2\ARCHIVE"
$YourDirToCompress_1 ="C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country2\ARCHIVE"


$SourcePath_2 = "C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country3"
$TargetPath_2 = "C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country3\ARCHIVE"
$YourDirToCompress_2 ="C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country3\ARCHIVE"

$Days = "7"
$Date = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm 

Write-Verbose $Activity
Get-Childitem -recurse -Path $SourcePath  | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$days)} | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $YourDirToCompress\$date.zip -update
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SourcePath  -Force | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$days)} | Remove-Item -Force

Write-Verbose $Activity
Get-Childitem -recurse -Path $SourcePath_1  | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$days)} | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $YourDirToCompress_1\$date.zip -update
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SourcePath_1  -Force | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$days)} | Remove-Item -Force

Write-Verbose $Activity
Get-Childitem -recurse -Path $SourcePath_2  | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$days)} | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $YourDirToCompress_2\$date.zip -update
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SourcePath_2  -Force | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$days)} | Remove-Item -Force
```

Can somebody tell me if a loop can be written to do archive  above 3 subfolders instead of writing the compress-archive and delete command line 3 times.

I loop is possible then please let me know whether 8 different scripts need to be written for 8 interfaces or with a single script it can handle all 8 interfaces and its subfolders??

I appreciate the help...

Comment: Yes it can, be sure to read up on the PS documentation pertaining to loops (there are several ways). Remember that SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

one possibility :

```
$AllDir=@(
@('C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country1',  'C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country1\ARCHIVE'),
@('C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country2', 'C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country2\ARCHIVE'),
@('C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country3', 'C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country3\ARCHIVE')
)

$Days = "7"
$Date = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm
$MaxDate =(get-date).AddDays(-$days)

$AllDir | %{

$SourcePath=$_[0]
$YourDirToCompress=$_[1]

Get-Childitem -recurse -Path $SourcePath  | Where LastWriteTime -lt $MaxDate | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $YourDirToCompress\$date.zip -update
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SourcePath  | Where LastWriteTime -lt $MaxDate | Remove-Item -Force

}
```

Comment: Hi There,

i tested it for lower file counts , it worked really fast.
But for 2500 xml files of 5kb-6kb each it took around 6 min to complete the archive and deleting process. Is there any way to speed up the process or it is dependant upon system memory usage and performance??

Comment: that's why i have proposed an other solution where compress is created and not updated

Comment: How can we use 7zip instead of compress-archive?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a generic method :

```
#take all country directory
$AllDirCountry=Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\529817\TEST\Country*" -directory

$Days = 7
$Date = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss-fffff
$MaxDate =(get-date).AddDays(-$days)

$AllDirCountry | %{

#build path
$SourcePath=$_.FullName
$YourDirToCompress="{0}\ARCHIVE" -f $_.FullName
$ArchiveDay="{0}\{1}" -f $YourDirToCompress, $Date
$ZipFile="{0}\{1}.zip" -f $YourDirToCompress, $Date


#remove archive day
Remove-Item $ArchiveDay -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#create archive directory if not exists
New-Item $YourDirToCompress -ItemType Directory -Force

#create archive of day directory if not exists
New-Item $ArchiveDay -ItemType Directory -Force

#move directory and file except files into archive directory
Get-Childitem -recurse -Path $SourcePath  | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $MaxDate -and $_.Directory -notlike "$YourDirToCompress*"} | move-Item -Destination $ArchiveDay -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#compress archive day
Compress-Archive "$ArchiveDay" -DestinationPath $ZipFile

#remove archive day
Remove-Item $ArchiveDay -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}
```

Comment: I am trying to run it automatically using task scheduler but script not running by task scheduler. 
powershell version is 5.1.17763.1490
OS is windows 10.
Execution-Policy is set as Bypass.